# Fill image in a div from center

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jpreloader

While the entire page is loading; the yellow circle needs to start with 1 thin line from center and will ‘form/fill’ the entire circle.

I have used the jPreloader. I am not sure how to start loading the logo from center. Currently, the height is being animated as the page loads.

Javascript where the height is being assigned to the div.

```
$(jBar).stop().animate({
        height: per + '%'
    }, 500, 'linear');
```

CSS where the logo is placed:

```
#jpreBar {
     border-radius:0%;
     -moz-border-radius:0%;
     -webkit-border-radius:0%;

     background: url(../images/logo.jpg) left top no-repeat;

     animation: progress 2s linear infinite;
     -moz-animation: progress 2s linear infinite;
     -webkit-animation: progress 2s linear infinite;
     -ms-animation: progress 2s linear infinite;
     -o-animation: progress 2s linear infinite; 
}
```

The animation needs to be like this, left to right:

[image: Animation]

Comment: could you not just position your image using `center center` instead of `left top`?

Comment: That makes the logo move too, check the link. The logo comes from top to bottom, it is better but still not like client wants.

Comment: Just some advise, you should declare -webkit-,-moz-,-ms- and -o-animation and animation without prefix after all others, the order is important !

Answer (score 1):

Try this code from my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZbkvL/1/). Think this will help you and adds the functionality to you loading screen. *The animation time and borders were added by me to test everything.*

**HTML:**

```
<div id="outer">
    <div id="jpreBar"></div>
</div>

<input id="input" value="0" />
<button id="button">Update</button>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#button').click(function(){
      var per = $('#input').val();

      var height = per;
      backgroundy = -176 + 176 * (per/100);
      margintop = 176 - 176 * (per/100);

      $('#jpreBar').stop().animate({
         'height': height + '%',
         'background-position-y': backgroundy + 'px',
         'margin-top': margintop + 'px'
      }, 5000, 'linear');
   });  
});
```

**CSS**

```
#jpreBar {
 border-radius:0%;
 -moz-border-radius:0%;
 -webkit-border-radius:0%;

 background-image: url("http://50.87.144.37/~projtest/team/design/yellowmedia/images/logo.jpg");
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: 0px -176px;
 height: 0%;
 margin-top: 176px;

 animation: progress 2s linear infinite;
 -moz-animation: progress 2s linear infinite;
 -webkit-animation: progress 2s linear infinite;
 -ms-animation: progress 2s linear infinite;
 -o-animation: progress 2s linear infinite; 

 border: 0px solid black;
}

#outer{
 border: 0px solid black;
 height: 351px;
}
```

Comment: I am using the logo in the context of pre loading. The logo will be relative to the amount of page loaded so I cannot give a static animation time period.

Comment: ok u are right, so i updated my js - [look at here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZbkvL/1/)